# Meaning of 'take it to the hoes'

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context, slang

I came across the following sentence:

> You can just take it to the hoes on Broadway if you need to get your freak on.

And not only can I not understand the phrase 'take it to the hoes' but I also couldn't find any references to it on the Internet.

Is it some kind of neologism? What do you think it means?

Comment: May I ask what I have written inappropriately to deserve downvotes? By no means it is about votes themself but I would like to be aware of my past mistakes.

Comment: Some people appear to believe this is a General Reference question - that is, one which may be resolved by consulting a standard reference work. So it may be closed; but I thank you for introducing me to the charming phrase "get your freak on" :)

Answer (score 4):

The phrase here is "Take it to" rather than "take it to the hoes." The only thing that makes this a bit confusing is that the thing that the person is taking (or carrying) is probably not an object, but rather some objective, goal, or request. The speaker of the quote is suggesting that needing to get your freak on is best solved by taking that problem to the hoes on Broadway.

A very common use of the phrase "Take it to" is "Take it to the other room", where someone is doing something in a place that is either inappropriate or otherwise undesirable. Here, it refers to the execution of the activity and not necessarily a physical object.

Comment: Okay, now it makes sense to me. But being still somewhat unsatisfied I looked into the word 'hoes' itself and only then I realized it is plural from 'ho' rather than 'hoe' - and from that moment everything became clear to me.

Comment: Haha, sorry! I didn't realize that was the point of confusion.